# Toggle table inside 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a toggle event to the table when I click on the title.

I have this kind of html:

```
<div class="processs">
    <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title</b>
    </span>
    <br>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
<div class="processs">
    <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title 2</b>
    </span>
    <br>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
<div class="processs">
    <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title 3</b>
    </span>
    <br>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

So I tried

```
$('.process_title').click(function(e)
{
  $(this).next('table').toggle();
  console.log('test');
});
```

I also tried `.closest` but it did not worked

Comment: The really obvious solution would be to replace the span with a div, and remove the break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation on the [`.next()` method](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

> `.next()` - Get the **immediately following sibling of each element** in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

It's not working because the `table` element isn't the immediate following sibling element.

You could use `.nextAll()`, then chain `.first()` to get the first match from the set:

```
$('.process_title').click(function(e) {
  $(this).nextAll('table').first().toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.process_title').click(function(e) {
  $(this).nextAll('table').first().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="processs">
  <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title</b>
    </span>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="processs">
  <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title 2</b>
    </span>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="processs">
  <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title 3</b>
    </span>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Of course, you could also use `$(this).siblings('table')` but that would select *all* sibling `table` elements rather than the first following sibling `table`.

Comment: Bang on, that's the technique I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(this).siblings('table')`. Currently you're only grabbing the next element, but the code above will instead grab any siblings which are of tag type table.

As mentioned by others, this would fail if there are more `table` tags inside of your `.process` element. Going off of your HTML it doesn't look like this is the case, but in general I would suggest you add a class to the `table` element you want so that you are only grabbing that one.

It is generally better to use classes or ids rather than tag names, since the problem above will present itself

Comment: But this would toggle all sibling table elements. If there are more `table` elements in the `.processs` element, this may not work as the OP expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `parent` or `closest` like following :

```
$('.process_title').click(function(e){
  $(this).parent().find('table').toggle();
  //OR
  $(this).parents('.processs').find('table').toggle();
  //OR
  $(this).closest('.processs').find('table').toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.process_title').click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('.processs').find('table').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="processs">
    <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title</b>
    </span>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
      <td>....</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="processs">
    <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title 2</b>
    </span>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
      <td>....</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="processs">
    <span class="process_title">
        <b>Title 3</b>
    </span>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
      <td>....</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```